# Duplicate submit during the reload of a php page

Tags: php, forms, submit

I'm a newbie in php and I'm playing around trying to write a mini chat web app. Here is my code: a page for connecting to the database are retrieving all informations have been posted preceedingly.

```
 <?php
     try{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=chat', 'root', '');
 }
 catch(Exception $e)
 {
     die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
 }

    $myname =$_POST["myname"];
    $message =$_POST["message"];
    $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO users(myname, message) VALUES(
       :myname,
       :message)');
       $req->execute(array(
          'myname' => $myname,
          'message' => $message,
        ));
     include('page1.php');
     $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT myname, message FROM users ORDER
        BY ID DESC');

        while ($mydata = $reponse->fetch())
        {
           echo '<p>' .($mydata['myname']) .
           '</strong> : ' . ($mydata['message']) . '</p>';
                    }  
?>
```

Another page which contain my form where users come and post their messages

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<title>chat</title>
</head>
<body>
  <fieldset width="90">
         <marquee>my mini chat </marquee>
         <form method="post" action="enregisteur.php">

           <label  for="Identifier">  Identifier :</label>
           <input type="text" name="myname" id="myname" value="myname" placeholder="myname"/>
           <br>
           <label  for="message"> Messages  :</label>
           <textarea name="message" id="message" value="message">
           </textarea>
                       <br>
           <input type="submit" name="validate" value=" validate " size="15"/>

       </form>
        </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

This works well but there is a little issue that I want to get ripe of: I a user say user1 comes and enter user1 and the messages Hello and then clicks on submit. The information goes to the database and it is displayed on the web page. If he there goes ahead and do a reload of the page without clicking on submit the same information is sent to the database and displayed again on the web play. That is we would have something like this on the web page

After clicking on submit
  user1: Hello
After reloading the page 
  user1: Hello
  user1: Hello

This happen after every reload

Please any help will be welcoming.
Thanks.

Comment: To dynamicly reload some data without reloading the entire page, you should look the "AJAX" technology :) !

Comment: I don't think that's the issue here, from what I understand when someone submits 'some text' and reloads the page the text is sent twice to the db.

Comment: The SELECT and the INSERT are on the same page there, that can be a problem too. But yeah you're right, it's not the solution to the problem here, but put a protection to avoid double INSERT into DB when reloading the page is far from the current level of OP, I think he should see the bigger picture before deciding what to do here :)

Comment: I agree @Julqas. berry are you doing the tutorial from open classrooms ?

Comment: @Ivan yes I'm getting my tutorials from open classrooms

Answer (score 0):

separate your insert and select query to different pages:

create a new page and move your insert query:

```
<?php
     try{
    $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=chat', 'root', '');
 }
 catch(Exception $e)
 {
     die('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
 }

    $myname =$_POST["myname"];
    $message =$_POST["message"];
    $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO users(myname, message) VALUES(
       :myname,
       :message)');
       $req->execute(array(
          'myname' => $myname,
          'message' => $message,
        ));


    header('location:enregisteur.php');
?>
```

And change your form action to new page